# PHP 7.2 проблема соединения с dbf через PDO

Tags: php, pdo, php7

У кого есть опыт работы с dbf на PHP 7.2 
При попытке подключиться

```
$this->dbase = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=$this->path;default-character-set=utf8;");
```

выдает ошибку

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию

А вот на PHP 7.1 такое подключение работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: А вы уверенны что необходимый драйвер(extension) установлен?

Comment: да, в ini я включил одинаковые DLL что на 7.1 что на 7.2

Comment: @EugeneOleynikov Вы проверьте, что драйвер реально работает... Может быть вы подключили, но не правильно, или сервер не перезагрузили.

Comment: смотрю настройки через phpinfo() и там есть PDO и PDO_ODBC

Comment: нуууу скачал php 72 x86  и все заработало с PDO. На php 72 x64 не работает (ОП win7 64-разрядность). хм ...

Comment: Обратите внимание, что если бы проблема была в отсутствии модуля PHP - то ошибка была бы от PDO вида `PDOException: could not find driver`. А так модуль для odbc у вас есть, но сам по себе этот odbc - ещё одна абстракция. Проблема дальше с системной настройкой этого самого odbc. (дальше не подскажу, всякой странной экзотикой вроде виндовых серверов не занимаюсь)

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что для x64 нужно использовать {Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)}